# Where in the CARs does it say that we need to perform a walk-around each day?

Tags: general-aviation, ppl

I understand to keep an aircraft airworthy, one of the items that must be followed is a walk-around each day. I've been browsing through the CARs for a couple hours now and I couldn't find anything on walk-arounds or pre-flight inspections in either the CARs or the AIM. Any help?

Comment: Not too long ago there were no regulations at all, yet there were good pilots and bad ones. A good pilot puts his trust in his own judgement and training, not regulations.

Answer (score 9):

> 14 CFR §91.7 Civil aircraft airworthiness.
>
> (a) No person may operate a civil aircraft unless it is in an
> airworthy condition.
>
> (b) The pilot in command of a civil aircraft is responsible for
> determining whether that aircraft is in condition for safe flight. The
> pilot in command shall discontinue the flight when unairworthy
> mechanical, electrical, or structural conditions occur.

How are you going to determine if an aircraft is in a condition for safe flight without doing a pre-flight inspection?

Comment: What about commercial pilots that fly something like the B737? They don't do walk-arounds before each flight as it's only legally required to do it once per day plus it takes way too long. I'm asking where in the air laws specifically say only one walk-around per-day is required.

Comment: There's no regulation that specifically states a walk-around is required, commercial organizations mandate it as part of their procedures as they recognize it's a critical step in complying with the regulation. Smart private pilots will do the same.

Comment: @YingTaurus I know several airlines where they do a walk around before every flight. As a minimum it involves a visual check of engines, leading and trailing edges, wheels/tyres, wheel wells, static and pitot ports. On a 737 size aircraft it is usually completed in under 10 minutes. Really not an excuse to skip it.

Comment: Every day, no, before every flight, yes.

Comment: @GdD I was taught all throughout my PPL training that a walk around each day must be completed, and the first person that does the walk around must sign in the journey log saying walk arounds are complete in order to keep the aircraft airworthy.

Comment: That's the procedural rules of the group or flight school you are in @YingTaurus, it's not a regulation.